# SVG logo too small

Tags: html, xml, svg

I can't find out why my logo is too small. This is a problem with the SVG, it's too small comparing with others svg logo that I've used. You can see the picture bellow.
[image: logo]

Do you see the small blue point at the top-left of the menu? Well that is the logo. There is no problem with CSS because I've tried another logo (chrome logo to be specific) and it looks good.
Here you have the svg code.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <!-- Creator: CorelDRAW X7 -->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
    viewBox="0 0 29700 21000"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <defs>
      <style type="text/css">
       <![CDATA[
        .fil0 {fill:#0496ff}
        .fil1 {fill:#F8F8FD}
        .fil2 {fill:#3245AA;fill-rule:nonzero}
       ]]>
      </style>
     </defs>
     <g id="Capa_x0020_1">
      <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
      <circle class="fil0" cx="15466" cy="8645" r="2938"/>
      <path class="fil1" d="M15129 6849c-554,-184 -1785,23 -2016,623 -279,725 -52,2348 503,3094 25,21 39,32 69,53 322,173 424,199 822,227 2510,173 2220,-3465 622,-3997zm-1567 953c-52,609 117,1701 283,2287 78,219 -19,139 346,196 213,34 411,-8 601,-101 392,-195 420,-935 360,-1302 -145,-896 -479,-1383 -1386,-1149 -42,11 -165,40 -204,69z"/>
      <path class="fil0" d="M17743 6335c123,134 209,259 315,405 185,270 298,510 402,824 967,2926 -1638,4620 -3839,4213 -1228,-227 -2335,-1165 -2614,-2769 -48,-271 -45,-861 21,-1094l25 -117c7,-45 29,-95 22,-125 -46,79 -64,141 -87,245 -186,823 -129,1483 170,2237 11,28 22,56 34,84 246,571 650,1021 1121,1427 1418,1190 3695,866 4916,-412 2143,-2243 577,-5662 -2367,-6048 -338,-44 -708,-14 -1043,47l-146 29c-26,5 -8,-2 -30,9 -19,9 4,3 -26,17 139,4 298,-37 439,-43 49,-2 109,-11 155,-11 986,-1 1841,387 2532,1082z"/>
      <path class="fil1" d="M17275 7474c55,0 100,13 151,21 98,13 209,33 306,51 448,54 -44,-607 -314,-693 -205,-76 -410,-122 -624,-173 -119,-19 -247,-21 -335,28 -113,64 -89,146 -93,289 -17,874 246,1564 187,3217 -1,120 -38,236 -19,361 27,167 121,165 261,137 19,-4 21,-2 40,-8 14,-4 51,-22 65,-29 99,-50 147,-90 221,-167 55,-59 15,-18 61,-87 226,-333 158,-1041 238,-1198 15,-28 117,-49 144,-54 136,-27 308,-78 414,-162 128,-102 124,-307 112,-470 -29,-367 -268,-286 -467,-288 -289,-3 -214,108 -292,-446 -10,-74 -59,-270 -56,-329z"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

I don't really work with SVG, this logo was made by an agency. So I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: It's like Finding Svg Nemo.

Comment: I would say, based on my limited experience, that the viewbox is way too big. Not sure how you'd fix that, though.

Comment: `viewBox="11800 5050 7500 7500"` would be a pretty good fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes the logo the same size as the viewbox:

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xml:space="preserve"
   version="1.1"
   style="clip-rule:evenodd;fill-rule:evenodd;image-rendering:optimizeQuality;shape-rendering:geometricPrecision;text-rendering:geometricPrecision"
   viewBox="0 0 7342.1074 7220.7803"
   id="svg32"
   sodipodi:docname="logo.svg"
   width="7342.1074"
   height="7220.7803"
   inkscape:version="0.92.1 r15371"><metadata
   id="metadata36"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
       rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
         rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><sodipodi:namedview
   pagecolor="#ffffff"
   bordercolor="#666666"
   borderopacity="1"
   objecttolerance="10"
   gridtolerance="10"
   guidetolerance="10"
   inkscape:pageopacity="0"
   inkscape:pageshadow="2"
   inkscape:window-width="1107"
   inkscape:window-height="713"
   id="namedview34"
   showgrid="false"
   inkscape:zoom="0.040190476"
   inkscape:cx="2968.8339"
   inkscape:cy="1904.8506"
   inkscape:window-x="190"
   inkscape:window-y="33"
   inkscape:window-maximized="0"
   inkscape:current-layer="svg32" />
 <defs
   id="defs20">
  <style
   type="text/css"
   id="style18">
   <![CDATA[
    .fil0 {fill:#0496ff}
    .fil1 {fill:#F8F8FD}
    .fil2 {fill:#3245AA;fill-rule:nonzero}
   ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g
   id="Capa_x0020_1"
   transform="translate(-11881.166,-5184.0702)">
  <metadata
   id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer" />
  <circle
   class="fil0"
   cx="15466"
   cy="8645"
   r="2938"
   id="circle23"
   style="fill:#0496ff" />
  <path
   class="fil1"
   d="m 15129,6849 c -554,-184 -1785,23 -2016,623 -279,725 -52,2348 503,3094 25,21 39,32 69,53 322,173 424,199 822,227 2510,173 2220,-3465 622,-3997 z m -1567,953 c -52,609 117,1701 283,2287 78,219 -19,139 346,196 213,34 411,-8 601,-101 392,-195 420,-935 360,-1302 -145,-896 -479,-1383 -1386,-1149 -42,11 -165,40 -204,69 z"
   id="path25"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   style="fill:#f8f8fd" />
  <path
   class="fil0"
   d="m 17743,6335 c 123,134 209,259 315,405 185,270 298,510 402,824 967,2926 -1638,4620 -3839,4213 -1228,-227 -2335,-1165 -2614,-2769 -48,-271 -45,-861 21,-1094 l 25,-117 c 7,-45 29,-95 22,-125 -46,79 -64,141 -87,245 -186,823 -129,1483 170,2237 11,28 22,56 34,84 246,571 650,1021 1121,1427 1418,1190 3695,866 4916,-412 2143,-2243 577,-5662 -2367,-6048 -338,-44 -708,-14 -1043,47 l -146,29 c -26,5 -8,-2 -30,9 -19,9 4,3 -26,17 139,4 298,-37 439,-43 49,-2 109,-11 155,-11 986,-1 1841,387 2532,1082 z"
   id="path27"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   style="fill:#0496ff" />
  <path
   class="fil1"
   d="m 17275,7474 c 55,0 100,13 151,21 98,13 209,33 306,51 448,54 -44,-607 -314,-693 -205,-76 -410,-122 -624,-173 -119,-19 -247,-21 -335,28 -113,64 -89,146 -93,289 -17,874 246,1564 187,3217 -1,120 -38,236 -19,361 27,167 121,165 261,137 19,-4 21,-2 40,-8 14,-4 51,-22 65,-29 99,-50 147,-90 221,-167 55,-59 15,-18 61,-87 226,-333 158,-1041 238,-1198 15,-28 117,-49 144,-54 136,-27 308,-78 414,-162 128,-102 124,-307 112,-470 -29,-367 -268,-286 -467,-288 -289,-3 -214,108 -292,-446 -10,-74 -59,-270 -56,-329 z"
   id="path29"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   style="fill:#f8f8fd" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I'm not sure how much of what Inkscape added is actually necessary (like I commented above, SVG isn't my forte), but if you save this in an .svg file and then load it with an `<img />` tag, you can set whatever size you actually need. Otherwise, setting the height and width attributes would work as well.

Here's a jsFiddle with the height and width set to 400px: https://jsfiddle.net/sogdk632/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I've downloaded inkscape and resize the logo with this program and it works.

Answer (score 0):

- Download Inkscape
- Resize the logo
- Select the whole logo (ctrl + a)
- export the selection as png (shift + ctrl + e)
- click export

Comment: Hi, that is exactly what I did and it works but I've exported the graphic as svg.

Answer (score 0):

It was obviously designed in the middle of a big page and didn't have the artboard size set correctly.

All you needed to do was adjust the `viewBox` values so that they match the logo more closely.

```
viewBox="11802 5162 7470 7250"
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <!-- Creator: CorelDRAW X7 -->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
    viewBox="11802 5162 7470 7250"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <defs>
      <style type="text/css">
       <![CDATA[
        .fil0 {fill:#0496ff}
        .fil1 {fill:#F8F8FD}
        .fil2 {fill:#3245AA;fill-rule:nonzero}
       ]]>
      </style>
     </defs>
     <g id="Capa_x0020_1">
      <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
      <circle class="fil0" cx="15466" cy="8645" r="2938"/>
      <path class="fil1" d="M15129 6849c-554,-184 -1785,23 -2016,623 -279,725 -52,2348 503,3094 25,21 39,32 69,53 322,173 424,199 822,227 2510,173 2220,-3465 622,-3997zm-1567 953c-52,609 117,1701 283,2287 78,219 -19,139 346,196 213,34 411,-8 601,-101 392,-195 420,-935 360,-1302 -145,-896 -479,-1383 -1386,-1149 -42,11 -165,40 -204,69z"/>
      <path class="fil0" d="M17743 6335c123,134 209,259 315,405 185,270 298,510 402,824 967,2926 -1638,4620 -3839,4213 -1228,-227 -2335,-1165 -2614,-2769 -48,-271 -45,-861 21,-1094l25 -117c7,-45 29,-95 22,-125 -46,79 -64,141 -87,245 -186,823 -129,1483 170,2237 11,28 22,56 34,84 246,571 650,1021 1121,1427 1418,1190 3695,866 4916,-412 2143,-2243 577,-5662 -2367,-6048 -338,-44 -708,-14 -1043,47l-146 29c-26,5 -8,-2 -30,9 -19,9 4,3 -26,17 139,4 298,-37 439,-43 49,-2 109,-11 155,-11 986,-1 1841,387 2532,1082z"/>
      <path class="fil1" d="M17275 7474c55,0 100,13 151,21 98,13 209,33 306,51 448,54 -44,-607 -314,-693 -205,-76 -410,-122 -624,-173 -119,-19 -247,-21 -335,28 -113,64 -89,146 -93,289 -17,874 246,1564 187,3217 -1,120 -38,236 -19,361 27,167 121,165 261,137 19,-4 21,-2 40,-8 14,-4 51,-22 65,-29 99,-50 147,-90 221,-167 55,-59 15,-18 61,-87 226,-333 158,-1041 238,-1198 15,-28 117,-49 144,-54 136,-27 308,-78 414,-162 128,-102 124,-307 112,-470 -29,-367 -268,-286 -467,-288 -289,-3 -214,108 -292,-446 -10,-74 -59,-270 -56,-329z"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```